# How to read input from user's keyboard

Tags: python

I'm a noob in programming (in python), I want to know how I could read data from user's keyboard in order to make a calculator for example based on the numbers he entered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for sure a duplicate question but you can use this:

```
a = int(input("Enter the first number"))
b = int(input("Enter the second number"))
```

... do what you want with `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` statement is used for this purpose.
But the input statement accepts string input, so in order to take integral input, you need to convert the input to integers. Code:

```
a = int(input('Enter a Number'))
```

This will prompt the user to provide input and then store it in the variable `a`. You can then use it anywhere. In the same way, if you want to input decimal numbers, you need to convert the type to `float`:

```
a = float(input('Enter a Number'))
```